# How to update entity with @Version field properly?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I've the following entity:

```
@Entity
public class Tenant {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @Version
    private Instant version = Instant.now()
}
```

and want this piece of code (which goal is to updated the entity with values from DTO - DTO has fields 1:1 with entity) to fail with optimistic lock exception:

```
Option<Tenant> updateTenant(Long id, UpdateTenantDTO dto) {
   return repository
      .findById(dto.getId())
      .map(tenant -> {
          tenant.setVersion(dto.getVersion());

          if (isNotEmpty(dto.getName())) {
             tenant.setName(dto.getName());
          }
          return tenant;
       })
       .map(repository::save);
 }
```

Unfortunately the exception never occurs and invalid version is set in DTO. How to update the entity in a reliable way? I've no transactions defined. Somehow when `save` is called it sets the new `version` and even in the DB `version` is different saves it smoothly.